# How can I fix "javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)"?

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception, imageicon

I'm making a simple program of a PONG game, and my problem comes from the Main method which i wanted to set an image icon and it shoots me a NullPointerException.

I'm working with Eclipse IDE 2019,06 and the Java Compiler 12.0.1. The image that I am using is .jpg.
I've tried to change the directory of the image and nothing :(.
The directory of the image is in a folder which is in the same folder of the main class.

This is my frame code:

```java
    public class Menu {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Menu window = new Menu();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    window.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    window.frame.setTitle("PONG!");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Menu() {
        frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(Menu.class.getResource("/icon.jpg")).getImage());
        initialize();
    }
```

So this is the error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at gui.Menu.<init>(Menu.java:57)
    at gui.Menu$1.run(Menu.java:42)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I hope you can help me with this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess line 57 of `Menu.java` is this line:

```
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(Menu.class.getResource("/icon.jpg")).getImage());
```

It looks like `frame` has not been initialized and therefore is null. That's why you get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Dude, thanks for open my eyes. As you said, frame hasn't initialized so i write the code line on the init method, so has worked. Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you work with the Maven build system (e.g. netbeans 11.3, maven 3.3.x), you have to take care where you place your resources. The "/icon.jpg" path is relative to your resources directory. Try to create a directory named "resources" (sic!) as a subdirectory of the java main source directory. For example, the path to "resources" should be

```
<Project root>/src/main/resources
```

You place your image files in this directory or a maybe a subdirectory /src/main/resources/icons/icon.jpg